# Fantasy - need to find this book - museum related with unicorns and a pegasus

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a story I read maybe 5 years ago?

- Kid's father is "forgotten"
- kid try to find him and goes through a portal/doorway accidentally and finds himself in a fantasy land where everything forgotten is sent to.
- I think it revolves around a museum (possibly in Berlin)
- There was a desert filled with stones with names on it. And I think it meant that if there was your name there you were forgotten in the real world.
- The bad guy is erasing the artefacts and people from the museum so the boy tries to save the world
- he gets help from a pegasus and eventually find everyone and happy ending.
- I think the guardian of the doorway was a unicorn (that is ready to stab you)

Comment: There's a small chance this is Madeline L'Engle's "A Wrinkle In Time" trilogy. I don't remember the "forgotten" theme or the desert filled with stones, but the forgotten father and pegasus match.

Answer (score 7):

I am sure this is [Ralf Isau's](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ralf_Isau) "Museum of lost memories", even if I was not able to find an English edition. The original is in German, "Das Museum der verlorenen Erinnerung".

Twins, a boy and a girl, were asked by the police where their father is. He, a night officer in the Berlin Pergamon Museum, is accused of a crime.

Surprised the children notice, that they have no memory of their father and start to investigate. They find some information at the storage room under the roof, and the boy decides to go through the Ishtar gate to the fantasy world, to find his father. The girl stays in the real world to search for more information.

At the Ishtar gate, there is painted a golden beast with a horn on its forehead. The boy is welcomed in the fantasy world by a copper unicorn.

The villain is deleting memories of Berlin's people step by step.

A pegasus is helping the boy to travel from challenge to challenge and to escape.

I cannot exactly remember the desert with stones and names. But I [here is a synopsis](https://www.isau.de/pdfs/museum_e.pdf) where it is mentioned in English.

The museum and the gate with the painted beasts are real in Berlin.

[image: Cover of the first German version of the book. Visible is the blue Ishtar gate with a whirl in the middle.]